# Connecting to a Checkpoint VPN-1 from Snow Leopard?

Tags: macos, vpn, osx-snow-leopard, ipsec

Checkpoint SecureClient doesn't work with Snow Leopard, so I've been looking for some other options.  [VPN Tracker](http://www.equinux.com/us/products/vpntracker/index.html) appears to work, but lacks username/password (XAUTH RSA) authentication support (PSK and X.509 only, it seems), so I can't use it to connect to our VPN-1 box.

I've looked at [IPSecuritas](http://www.lobotomo.com/products/IPSecuritas/index.html), but I can't figure out how to configure it - specifically, mapping over the settings from the Checkpoint VPN-1 SecureClient.  IPSecuritas has a billion more options, which I presume of course SecureClient was just hiding from me because obviously it knows what to do to connect to a VPN-1, and the IPSecuritas forums are generally full of questions with no answers, so that doesn't really appear to be a quality avenue for support.

Does anyone have an XAUTH RSA IPSec VPN to a Checkpoint VPN-1 working in Snow Leopard, and what software did you use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was having the same issue and finally was able to get it working.  Here is a link to the screenshots:

[CheckPoint VPN and Snow Leopard](http://andrewshouldhave.blogspot.com/2009/08/checkpoint-vpn-and-snow-leopard-using.html)

Hope this helps.

Comment: That *almost* works, but I don't know what to put in for User FQDN, and I suspect it matters as I'm getting: "Message: '[0020] The user is not defined properly. (msg_obj :format (1.0) :id (VPN_USER_NOT_PROPERLY_DEFINED_2) :def_msg ("The user is not defined properly.") :arguments () )" from IKE.  Does this have to match up to some value on the server that I don't know about?

Comment: I put in the user name that I login with.

Comment: Annoyingly you also have to shut down any interfaces on your own machine that may overlap with the address space in the remote networks (even though with the VPN-1 SecureClient there isn't actually any bleed-through), so I have to whack my VMWare vmnet interfaces....anyone know how to control where VMWare decides to stick NAT'd interfaces?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get my IPSecuritas to work with VPN-1, I do however use Hybrid RSA, whenever I try using XAUTH RSA it doesn't work and in hybrid i dont have any certificates either..

basically try using hybrid rsa instead of xauth rsa

Comment: Sadly no go on that either...my connection is actually never getting out of Phase 1, so it's not even getting to an authentication step.  I suppose the thing to do is start fiddling with all the options in Phase 1 and see if I can get them to match up - maybe I can find a list of defaults for VPN-1 on the internet somewhere, as a place to start at least.

Comment: i just noticed that they released more recent version (3.3) then what i had before (3.2), try upgrading to more recent one regardless the case. also i remember when i create my connection first time i used wizard and believe it or not even though i was entering same settings i couldn't get to work, so try it again another time wizard i know that might sound stupid but thats how it worked for me...

Comment: oh yeah and another thing is, since snow leopard is officially out hopefully checkpoint get off of their lazy butts and do some actual work around there and make new version that is snow leopard compatible

Answer (score 1):

SecureClient has been updated for Snow Leopard support, download it here:

https://supportcenter.checkpoint.com/supportcenter/portal?eventSubmit_doShowproductpage&productTab=downloads&product=175&version=SecureClient%20for%20Mac

Comment: this link is dead

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using an existing Checkpoint Guide as a starting point? http://www.lobotomo.com/products/IPSecuritas/howto/Checkpoint%20SafeAtOffice.pdf

With the SonicWall I have at work I had to use their guide as a starting point and then change a couple settings that we had that were non-default.